# Java compiler fails to recognise static inner class

Tags: java, compiler-construction, static, inner-classes

This is quite a complicated error, so please bear with me.

I am seeing a weird error when trying to compile some Java code.  The compiler fails to recognise a *static inner class*.  Let us say that I am working on a class `MyClass`.  The static inner class which I need to use has an FQN of `x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass`.  This inner class is explicitly imported using its FQN.  The parent is also imported using its FQN.  Now there exists another package with (another, different FQN) which has a class `DesiredClass`.  This other DesiredClass is on the classpath, but it is not being explicitly imported.

Before I continue I should make it clear that it is not possible to change the names of these classes.

Now when I reference `Parent.DesiredClass` in my code, I use the **FQN** of `Parent.DesiredClass` to avoid any possible ambiguity.  But when I compile I get an error when I try to instantiate `Parent.DesiredClass`.  My code snippet:

```
x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass dc;
dc = new x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass();
```

This produces the following compile time error:

```
MyClass.java:123: an enclosing instance that contains x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass is required
   dc = new x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass();
           ^
```

It is important to note that the classes being linked to were compiled with different Java compilers:

- `MyClass` is intended to be compiled with Sun Java 1.4.2_18
- `x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass` and the *other* `DesiredClass` were compiled using *Microsoft Java*.

Again, unfortunately, these classes cannot be recompiled with more modern versions of Java.

Additionally, when actually trying to compile with Sun Java 1.4.2_18, the following exception occurs *within the compiler*:

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.4.2_18). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.code.Type.isSubTypes(Type.java:557)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Resolve.instantiate(Resolve.java:221)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Resolve.selectBest(Resolve.java:317)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Resolve.findMethod(Resolve.java:414)
        ...
        at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:1332)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:355)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.Main.compile(Main.java:569)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:36)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:27)
Error encountered running Java Compiler

Aborting compilation.
```

If I compile with a newer version of Java (1.5 onwards), then the compiler exception does not occur, but the abovementioned error still occurs.

Can anyone please explain this error?  Why does the compiler not recognise the static inner class as static, even if it is referred to using its FQN?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

==========

**EDIT**: The rabbit hole deepens.  After further investigation I found that the problem is triggered by a single line of code in one of the libraries which I need to have in my path.  I have access to the source code of this library, but do not compile it as part of my project.  The line of code (let's say it's in class `TheirClass`) does exactly what I am trying to do; i.e., instantiating `x.y.z.DesiredClass`.  If I remove this line of code in `TheirClass` (but not in `MyClass`), then I do not get the compile error.

So, in summary, the following **does not** work:

**MyClass.java**:

```
x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass dc;
dc = new x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass();
```

**TheirClass.java**:

```
x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass dc;
dc = new x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass();
```

The following **does** work:

**MyClass.java**:

```
x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass dc;
dc = new x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass();
```

**TheirClass.java**:

```
//x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass dc;
//dc = new x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass();
```

I am going to try and follow @Richard's advice and minimise the code so that I can post a sample of it.

Comment: Can you provide the code for `DesiredClass`? The error you're getting is what you usually see when trying to instantiate a non-static inner class without an instance of the enclosing class.

Comment: 'Static inner class' is a contradiction in terms. Either it is inner or it is static. See the JLS.

Comment: With all due respect, @EJP, the terms "inner" and "static" are not mutually exclusive.  An inner class need not necessarily be static.  I think a static class does need to be nested inside another class, though.  But it gains access to the members of the outer class, including the (static) private ones.  Therefore the term "static inner" is valid to differentiate it from non-static inner classes.

Comment: Here's how I think about this after reading the comments. An inner class cannot be static _by definition_.

For example, the Java Language Specification here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3 states:

"An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static"

So, while in practice, people may know generally what you're referring to when you say "static inner class", it's probably more correct to say "static nested class" or purists will disagree with your usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While still busy doing the low level investigations suggested by @Richard and @Stephen, I had a couple of ideas about this issue.

I first tried to extend `DesiredClass` with one which has a less ambiguous name and then see if it would work if I rather use the extended class.  It did not and caused the same error.

I then tried to instantiate `DesiredClass` using `Class.forName()`:

```
DesiredClass dc;
try {
    dc = (DesiredClass) Class.forName(classname).newInstance();
}
catch (Exception e) {

}
```

**This worked!**

Even though this is a bit messy, it allows me to continue with my work.  I would love to know what the root cause of the error is (perhaps some problem with the class loader which the compiler uses, especially considering that there are classes which have been compiled with different "brands" of compilers?), but the cost-benefit of spending more time trying to figure this out is not worth it.

Thank you to everyone who contributed.

Answer (score 2):

The error message `"an enclosing instance that contains x.y.z.Parent.DesiredClass is required"` means that the compiler *thinks* that `DesiredClass` is NOT `static`.

I suggest that you get hold of the `Parent$DesiredClass.class` file, and use `javap` to examine the compiled classes attributes.  That should tell you if the class you are compiling against is really a static inner class.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I had a look at the `javap` (verbose) output and nothing obviously wrong jumped out at me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying to trim this error down to the fewest possible classes.

### STEP 1

Take your custom code project, and see if you can trim the offending class down to a single line of code that fails the build. Then see if you can remove all other classes from your custom project, and still fail the build.

Do a bit of renaming of methods etc in this single class, to hide the "secret" info of production code, and hopefully you will have a source file you can post on this forum.

### STEP 2

Do the same for the product code that is being used (not the JAR file, the other class files).

Then for the JAR file stuff. At each point (laborious and boring), confirm you still get the same errors.

### STEP 3

Hopefully it was possible to replicate this problem with 3 class files, none of which contain any  production names/code etc. Post these for us to see - I think this is an interesting problem.

ymmv

Comment: Thanks Richard, I'll get on that and get back to you.